# How to run a random command every time I start a terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I have a doubt about script.I need to execute some random command when i open terminal its automatically execute that command.

For Example,
if i open first terminal the terminal will execute ls command and after that i open another terminal its execute df -h command and when i open thrid terminal its automatically top command.

This sequence will come simultaneously when i open terminal.

Please assist me how to write the script for it.

Comment: What have you tried this far? Does the random command you describe have to be run only when a shell is started in a (presumably X11) terminal window or every time a shell is started?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
r=$((RANDOM%3))      # generates a number in the range of 0 to 2
command[0]="ls"
command[1]="df -h"
command[2]="top"
eval ${command[$r]}  # executes command
unset command r
```